# Pascal's triangle in python?

Tags: python, pascals-triangle

I seem to be having a problem with creating a pascal's triangle in python, and I'm really realyl frustrated not finding the problem. Please help. Thanks.

Heres the code:

```
inpt = input("Enter levels: ")   #number of levels in a triangle
list1 = []
list2 = [1]

for a in range(inpt):
    list1.append(1)
    for x in range(a+1):
        if (x == 0 or x == a):
            list1[x]
        elif (x > 0 or x < a):
            list1[x] = list2[x] + list2[x-1]
    print list1
    list2 = list1
```

and it prints something like this:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 4, 8, 9, 1]
```

Comment: What do you think is the problem? It's doing exactly what you ask it to - what should it be doing instead? Note that `list2 = list1` means both names reference *the same object*, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `list2 = list1` you are saying that the two names `list1` and `list2` are referencing the same list.
To really copy the list, you can use `list2 = list1[:]` (or a module like [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html). See also [this question ("python list by value not by reference")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference))

```
for a in range(inpt):
    list1.append(1)
    for x in range(a+1):
        if (x == 0 or x == a):
            list1[x]
        elif (x > 0 or x < a):
            list1[x] = list2[x] + list2[x-1]
    print list1
    list2 = list1[:]
```

Comment: Oh my gosh you are my savior. Thanks so much everything already works like a charm ^^

Comment: don't need parens in your if/elif statements and what does `list1[x]` do?

Comment: @JoeSmart, `list1[x]` is essentially doing nothing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham apologies, being awake for 24 hours doesn't help my awareness, and I totally missed the "standalone" `list1[x]`, I thought you meant the use of `list1[x]` after the `elif` statement. Sorry for coming across cocky and patronizing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code.

`for x in range(a+1)` starts at 0 and goes all the  way to `a` because you are using `a+1`, you use if checks to avoid `0` and `a` so it would make more sense to start your range from `1` and loop over the `range(a)` thus removing the need for any `if/elif` checks:

```
for a in xrange(inpt):
    list1.append(1)
    for x in xrange(1, a):
        list1[x] = list2[x] + list2[x-1]
    print list1
    list2 = list1[:]
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to deep copy or clone your lists instead of list2=list1 as this will make both variables point to the same list.
Refer to [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)