# Problems with wrong values "return"-ed in Python ( a deep-copy issue )

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have defined the following function with Python:

```
def step(G,V1,V2):
    tempcut=sys.maxint
    for k in range(min(len(V1),len(V2))):
        V1, V2, C=Switch(G,V1,V2,k)
        print(C)
        if C<tempcut:
           tempcut=C
           best1=V1
           best2=V2
           print('enter')
           print(tempcut)
           print(best1)  
           print(best2)      
    return best1, best2, tempcut,
```

`G` is a graph object (with `networkx`), `V1` and `V2` are two lists (a partition of the nodes of `G`). The function `Switch(, , )` is another function that I've defined previously which returns an update of `V1` and `V2` and moreover an integer `C`.

My purpose is to return the lists `best1`, `best2` and the smallest value of `tempcut`. The function returns the correct value of `tempcut` but on the other hand it returns **the last values** of `V1` and `V2`, but not `best1` and `best2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy your list. You are changing it by reference. Check the [official Python FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference), [Thread](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python)

Try:

```
import copy

def step(G,V1,V2):
    tempcut=sys.maxint
    for k in range(min(len(V1),len(V2))):
        V1, V2, C=Switch(G,V1,V2,k)
        print(C)
        if C<tempcut:
           tempcut=C
           best1=copy.copy(V1) #or : best1= V1[:] as Serge suggested  
           best2=copy.copy(V2) #or : best2= V2[:] as Serge suggested  
           print('enter')
           print(tempcut)
           print(best1)  
           print(best2)      
    return best1, best2, tempcut,
```

Comment: You can also get a copy by simply using `best1 = V1[:]`

Comment: Yes! Several solutions are available (I added it as a comment). It has been mentioned to the thread (that's why I pointed to it).

Comment: Yes! Python uses names and not variables.

Answer (score 0):

A safer construct may do this:

```
import copy                                 # use copy as Taha proposed
def step( G, V1, V2 ):
    tempcut = sys.maxint
    best1   = []                            # init for a case if() would never come true
    best2   = []                            # init for a case if() would never come true
    for k in range( min( len( V1 ), len( V2 ) ) ):
        V1, V2, C = Switch( G, V1, V2, k )
        print( C )
        if C < tempcut:
           tempcut = C
           best1   = copy.copy( V1 )        # use copy as Taha proposed
           best2   = copy.copy( V2 )        # use copy as Taha proposed
           print( 'enter' )
           print( tempcut )
           print( best1 )
           print( best2 )
    return ( best1, best2, tempcut,  )      # return as tuple
```