# Python: How can I edit a copy of a list independently?

Tags: python, list, copy, nested

I have a nested `list A`.  I then let `list B=list A`.  When I try to edit list B by changing some of its elements using `B[1][2]=2`, `list A[1][2]` gets changed too.

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning a reference, so list B is actually pointing to list A. You would have to use copy of list. answered here:

[python list by value not by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3,4]]
    B = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        c = list(A[i])
        B.append(c)
```

Then you will be able to change B without changing A.

Answer (score -1):

instead of:

```
listB = listA
```

try:

```
listB = listA[:]
```

And here's an excellent explanation for why this happens:

http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Answer (score -2):

Edit *explain whole though process…*:

```
list = [[],[],[],[]]
a = 0
b = 3
list[a] = [1,2,3]
list[b] = list[a][:]
```

now `list[b]` is a copy and not the same list as `list[a]` and you cant edit them independently.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your solution will not work for nested lists, `list[a] = [1,2,3]` will yield `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Comment: @SiHa why should this not work? you have list with nested lists. a represents one of them, lets say the first one a=0 and be an other one, maybe the b=3. then you set a if it is not set and copy a to b?? i actually tested it out. ofc this wont work if you just copy paste it. (edited the code so people who just copy paste will understand my though process^)

Comment: Your code is clearer now, but it still doesn't answer the OP's problem. You have shown how to copy a list from one element of a nested list to another element of the *same* list. The OP wanted to copy an entire nested list to another nested list.

Comment: @SiHa uhh now i get what this list A and list B means ... a list called A and one called B. that totally confused me ;-)