# workarounds in python for appending list elements by value

Tags: python

I have a list consisting of just one dictionary item. I want to modify this item and append it to another list. When I append to another list, it still retains the pointers since it copies by reference by design.

As per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference) even if the list is copied using [:] notation, it still retains the link to its inner objects.

My question is how do I get around this limitation or is there a workaround for what I am trying to achieve? Here is the code snippet:

```
a=[]
b=[]
a=[{'sk' : 1, 'id' : 'P001', 'status' : 'NEW'}]
a[0]['sk']=a[0]['sk']+1
a[0]['status']='CURRENT'
b.append(a[0])
a[0]['sk']=a[0]['sk']+1
a[0]['status']='EXISTING'
b.append(a[0])
b
[{'id': 'P001', 'sk': 3, 'status': 'EXISTING'},
{'id': 'P001', 'sk': 3, 'status': 'EXISTING'}]
```

As you can see, changing [a] changes all elements in [b]. I also tried changing b[0], b[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference) etc. It still does the same.

Are there any workarounds for what I am trying to do?

Comment: `l[:]` is only a *shallow* copy; with a mutable container of mutable containers you need a *deep* copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call `.copy()` on `a` when you append it to `b`.

```
b = []
a = [{'sk' : 1, 'id' : 'P001', 'status' : 'NEW'}]
a[0]['sk'] += 1
a[0]['status'] = 'CURRENT'
b.append(a[0].copy())
a[0]['sk'] = a[0]['sk']+1
a[0]['status'] = 'EXISTING'
b.append(a[0])
print(b)

[{'sk': 2, 'id': 'P001', 'status': 'CURRENT'}, {'sk': 3, 'id': 'P001', 'status': 'EXISTING'}]
```

Comment: @ArvindKandaswamy No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.copy()` to copy the inner `dict`

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a=[{'sk' : 1, 'id' : 'P001', 'status' : 'NEW'}]
>>> a[0]['sk'] += 1
>>> a[0]['status']='CURRENT'
>>> b.append(a[0].copy())
>>> a[0]['sk'] += 1
>>> a[0]['status']='EXISTING'
>>> b.append(a[0].copy())
>>> b
[{'sk': 2, 'status': 'CURRENT', 'id': 'P001'},
 {'sk': 3, 'status': 'EXISTING', 'id': 'P001'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy lists, arrays and objects without only copying the pointer use this library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

And than `a = copy.deepcopy(b)`