# Python Creating a nested list with random module

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random, nested-lists

Let's say I want to create a nested list with number sequence, and I want no repeated list sequence.

i.e. I would like something like this: `[[1,2,3,4],[2,1,3,4],[4,2,3,1]]` ,where the `len` of list depend on how many non repeated number sequence I could generate in limited attempt (four attempts in below case)

So here my first attempt:

```
import random
rng = random.Random()
bd =list(range(4))
i = 0
result =[]

while i <4:
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    if bd not in result:
        result.append(bd)
    i +=1
print(result)
```

I created the a list `bd = [0,1,2,3]` first before entering the while loop.

While running the above code, I got surprisingly only one element in my nested list every time.

Result: `[[1, 2, 0, 3]]`

But if I modify the code a little bit, it works as I expected. 
Here my modified code:

```
import random
rng = random.Random()
i = 0
result =[]

while i <4:
    bd =list(range(4))
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    if bd not in result:
        result.append(bd)
    i +=1
print(result)
```

Result: `[[3, 2, 0, 1], [1, 0, 3, 2], [0, 1, 3, 2]]`

What I do is just reset the list `bd` in every loop over again.

As per my understanding the list `bd` would be shuffled in every loop, so resetting `bd` to `[0,1,2,3]` should be meaningless. 
Could somebody explain to me why the modified code works?  Thanks.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists and similar objects in Python are referred to **by reference**. Consider the following simple example:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
another_list = []

for i in range(5):
    another_list.append(a_list)
    a_list[0] = i + 10

print(another_list)
```

You would expect the output to be:

```
[[10, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 2, 3, 4, 5], [12, 2, 3, 4, 5], [13, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

However, the output you see is:

```
[[14, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 2, 3, 4, 5], [14, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Every time you call `another_list.append(a_list)`, you append a **reference** to `a_list`. You then change `a_list`, and previously appended references point to the changed list.

At the end, `a_list` is equal to `[14, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and `another_list` contains five identical references to this list.

---

Back to your case. To prevent this from happening to you, you can create a copy of the list every time you append it, [as documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference):

```
import random
rng = random.Random()
i = 0
result =[]

while i <4:
    bd =list(range(4))
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    if bd not in result:
        # Use [:] to create a slice of bd which actually contains the whole list
        result.append(bd[:])
    i +=1
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks Archimaredes. Everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

In your first attempt, you're shuffling and appending the *same* list to result every time. Try using a copy by taking a slice of the whole list: `bd[:]` is an entirely independent object that won't get changed when you shuffle the original `bd` next time round the loop.

```
import random
rng = random.Random()
bd =list(range(4))
i = 0
result =[]

while i <4:
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    if bd not in result:
        result.append(bd[:])
    i +=1
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1, 3, 0], [1, 2, 3, 0], [0, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This happend because you append `bd` to `result` and in the next iteration you use `bd`, they have the same reference.
In the second one you generate a new list(different reference)in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks WoLy :) clean and clear answer that solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

There's one little trouble with your code: shuffle performs an in-place change, so it changes the object your variable references. By running first code, you'll always get one result -- the last shuffling operation. To avoid this you should append a copy of list:

```
import random
rng = random.Random()
bd =list(range(4))
i = 0
result =[]

while i <4:
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    if bd not in result:
        result.append(bd[:])
    i +=1
print(result)
```