# Passing object parameter by value

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

Code:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

def length(stack):
    i = 0
    while not stack.is_empty():
        stack.pop()
        i += 1
    return i

s1 = Stack()
s1.push(3)
s1.push(2)
s1.push(1)
print(length(s1))
s1.pop()
```

Output:

```
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stack.py", line 26, in <module>
    s1.pop()
  File "Stack.py", line 12, in pop
    return self.items.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I want the function `length()` to be able to modify a copy of `s1` instead on changing `s1`. Is there any way to do this in python?

I am not allowed to directly use `s1.items` so I can't just use `s1[:]`. I can't modify the class either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list by value not by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference)

Comment: @MohammadNadeem Not really because the question states that accessing the `items` isn't possible (or allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module:

```
import copy

# ... your code ...

print(length(copy.deepcopy(s1)))  # pass a copy to the length function
```

Or if you want it without extra module and if you can alter the `length` function you could simply keep the `pop`ped items and `push` them again after you have the length:

```
def length(stack):
    i = 0
    tmp = []
    while not stack.is_empty():
        tmp.append(stack.pop())    # append them to your temporary storage
        i += 1
    for item in tmp:               # take the items saved in the temporary list
        stack.push(item)           # and push them into your stack again
    return i
```