# List assignment in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a code like below,when i print the list1 and list2 it shows same elements but i have added the 9 after the assignment of existing list1 to list2 so it should not show 9 in list2.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=list1
list1.insert(4,9)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

please clear my doubt.

Comment: Unlike other languages, in Python, `list2=list1` does _not_ make a separate copy of list1.  list1 and list2 refer to the _same_ value.  See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list by value not by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference)

Comment: i understand the point. thanks for your help.

Comment: Please search the web before asking questions , this question has about 80k views and so it can be easily reached!

Answer (score 8):

In python, a variable name is a *reference* to the underlying variable. Both `list1` and `list2` refer to the same list, so when you insert `9` into that list, you see the change in both. You need to make an explicit copy (using [the `copy` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html), slice notation `list2 = list1[:]`, or some other method) if you want them to be distinct.

Comment: what if i need that kind of requirement, i want a make a copy of list in another list for some purpose. how would i do that. please comment.

Comment: @hieko, look at [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47992113/14062356). you should use either `list2 = list1[:]` or `list2 list1.copy()`. I'd recommend the second since it is clearer.

Answer (score 4):

You are confused between,

**when we have different lists?** and **when an alias is created?**.

As you have written:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=list1
```

The above code snippet will map `list1` to `list2`.

To check whether two variables refer to the same object, you can use `is` operator.

```
>>> list1 is list2
# will return "True"
```

In your example, Python created one list, reference by `list1` & `list2`. So there are two references to the same object. We can say that object `[1,2,3,4]` is aliased as it has more than one name, and since lists are mutable. So changes made using `list1` will affect `list2`.

However, if you want to have different lists, you should do this:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2 = list1[:]  # here list2 is created as a copy of list1
>>> list1.insert(4, 9)
>>> print list1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9]
>>> print list2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

list1=[1,2,3,4]
then list1= list2 which means the id of both lists is the same. even the values are the same
then list1.insert(4,9) it means to insert the value 9 at index position 4
then the list1 is [1,2,3,4,9]
we know the id of both list1 and list2 is the same then the list1 and list2 values are also the same
list1=[1,2,3,4,9]
list2=[1,2,3,4,9]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).