How to take only the values of the array and not the entire array?
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
y.append(4)

print(x)

This code will return [1, 2, 3, 4] but I want only [1, 2, 3].
This works like I want it to:
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = []
y[0] = x[0]
y[1] = x[1]
y[2] = x[2]
# Or use a for loop here, instead.

y.append(4)

print(x)

Also, is there a way to get the current values of the array:
x = [foo(), bar(), someOtherChangingNumber(), datetime.now()]
# y = x's values - not the functions


print(y)


I'm a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish -- you have a list of values that is getting updated, and you want the values before the update? Are they always appended like that, or is there another process populating your list? In the case of the former, you may be able to get away with taking a list slice: x = y[:-1]. If there's a more complex process populating your list however, you'll need show us that process.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/47986224/26993270
