# Python array value unexpectedly changes after function call

Tags: python, scope

I have a small function which uses one list to populate another.  For some reason, the source list gets modified.  I don't have a single line that manipulates the source list `arr`.  I am probably missing the way Python deals with scope of variables, lists.  My expected output is for the list `arr` to remain the same after the function call.

```
numTestRows = 5
m = 2
def getTestData():
    data['test'] = []
    size_c = len(arr)
    for i in range(numTestRows):
        data['test'].append(arr[i%size_c])
        for j in range(m):
            data['test'][i].append('xyz')

#just a 2x5 str matrix
arr = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
print('Array before: ')
print( arr)
data = {}
getTestData()
print('Array after: ')
print( arr)
```

Output

```
Array before: 
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
Array after: 
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz']]
```

Comment: It's better if you passed your variables (`data` and `arr`) as arguments to `getTestData()`

Comment: Why? I know it's considered a good practice but what about cases when I need the variable across functions, global is better than passing to each one.

Comment: [Why are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: It appear to me that `data['test'].append(arr[i%size_c])` is appending a reference to the element of the array and `data['test'][i].append('xyz')` data to this object it has stored.

Comment: @pault I disagree that this is a duplicate question. The other question is mainly to do with the use of the * operator in creating a list which isn't relevant here. Here it appear to be how the the array is stored within the dictionary.

Comment: To fix the issue change the line `data['test'].append(arr[i%size_c])` to `data['test'].append(arr[i%size_c][:])` to make a new copy of the array when you are appending it to a dictionary rather than adding the reference to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference is about copying by value rather than by reference.

Comment: @Tim -It worked but I don't understand why ?Th e syntax you suggested conveys the same meaning .. In any case, the changes are to the data['test'] list, how does the arr list get affected without any assignment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-why-is-this-and-how-can-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

You've mis-handled the references in your list of lists (not a `matrix`).  Perhaps if we break this down a *little* more, you can see what's happening.  Start your main program with the two char lists as separate variables:

```
left  = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
right = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
arr = [left, right]
```

Now, look at what happens within your function at the critical lines.  On this first iteration, size_c is 2, i is 0 ...

```
    data['test'].append(arr[i%size_c])
```

This will append `arr[0]` to `data[`test`]`, which started as an empty list.  Now for the critical part: `arr[0]` is not a new list; rather, it's a *reference* to the list we now know as `left` in the main program.  There is only *one* copy of this list.

Now, when we get into the next loop, we hit the statement:

```
        data['test'][i].append('xyz')
```

`data['test'][i]` is a reference to the same list as `left` ... and this explains the appending to the original list.

You can easily copy a list with the suffix `[:]`, making a new slice of the entire list.  For instance:

```
data['test'].append(arr[i%size_c][:])
```

... and this should solve your reference problem.

Comment: You can also use `copy()`, which works more generally than just lists.