# trying to replace similar items in a list with a character

Tags: python, list, set

I have rar file that contains some data, and I want to make a directory structure out of that and save it in an excel file. I used rarfile library to read the data, but it prints the data out like this

```
Resources/Custom Brushes/ClothDamageVDM.ZBP, 55.02MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/ControledGravityFolds.ZBP, 0.14MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/GeoStitches.ZBP, 0.06MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/LeatherTexturer.ZBP, 0.23MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/MagicFolds_Hard.ZBP, 5.89MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/MagicFolds_Soft.ZBP, 5.89MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/PreasureSizeFolds.ZBP, 0.07MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/VDM-folds.ZBP, 9.41MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/WovenNanoBrush.ZBP, 0.05MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/Wrinkles_Wrap.ZBP, 0.75MB
Resources/Custom Brushes/Xfolds.ZBP, 0.52MB
Resources/Hotkeys.TXT, 0.0MB
Resources/Masking Alphas/Masking Fold Alpha 01.jpg, 0.29MB
```

I would like to replace the similar items in these lines with a comma so it is nicely arranged in the excel sheet.

I managed to turn these lines to a list of lists, each list contains the content of the lines separated by the /, now I would like to replace the repeated items with commas, and here is the problem i have encountered.

i wrote the following code to generate a new list populated with commas

```
original_list= [[1,2,1],[1,2,3],[1,3],[1,3,5]]
# copy a new list
new_list = original_list[:]

for i in range(1, len(new_list)):
    # adding the second item in the original list to a set a
    a = set(original_list[i])
    # adding the first item in the original list to a set b
    b = set(original_list[i-1])
    # getting the similar items between them in set c
    c = list(a.intersection(b))
    # for the length of the similar items, go through the new list and change similar items into a ,
    for d in range (0, len(c)):
        new_list[i][d] = ',' 


print(original_list)
print(new_list)

#both list are changed
```

but when I change the new list, the original changes as well. I don't know why when the new list is not a reference, I have used [:] to make sure it is a new list.

I'm quite sure there is a better method to what I am doing overall, so i would appreciate it if you guys can point me in the right direction. right now, I'm stuck at this.

thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an example of expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copying issue you are having is because you have nested lists, so `list[:]` doesn't go "deep enough". Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744968/3923163).

If you don't want to use a library, and you only need to copy on level deep, here is an example of a "brute force" "deep copy" using list comprehension to build a new list. This could be updated using recursion to copy multiple levels if needed, but you get the idea.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], 9]
b = a[:]
b[0].append(4)

print(a)
print(b)

new = [x[:] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in a]
new[0].append(5)
print()
print(a)
print(new)
```

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 9]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 9]

[[1, 2, 3, 4], 9]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 9]
```

If you are looking for a code review, then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the more appropriate place to ask your question once your code is working. Stack Overflow is more intended for code that is not working.

Comment: thank you. that answered it. quick question.Is there any reason why would I not use a library?

Comment: Since the `copy` library is native to python, this one isn't the greatest example of when you wouldn't want to, or couldn't, use one. An example of not being able to use a package would be using some new open source package behind a company firewall, or limitations when working within a cloud environment. For the record, I am all for using packages and not reinventing the wheel, but there are some situations when you have to.