# Python: using lower() at a cloned list results in endless loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to add every entry of a list in lowercase by using lower().
I am using this code to do the task:

```
MyList = ["EntryOne", "EntryTwo"]
TempList = MyList     #cloning MyList to TempList

for v in TempList:
    MyList.append(v.lower())     #Why is it also being appended into TempList ?
    print(MyList)
    print(TempList)




#expected output:
#["EntryOne", "EntryTwo", "entryone", "entrytwo"]
#["EntryOne", "EntryTwo"]
```

As you can see, the declaration of TempList is outside of the for loop, i am just declaring it at the beginning. There is no code in which Im appending the lowercase into TempList.

As a result this script loops forever.

Comment: Please look in to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference

Comment: *Nowhere* did you clone a list. `TempList = MyList` **never** copies anything. That simply assigns the *same list object* to another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is your statement in line #2:

```
TempList = MyList     #cloning MyList to TempList
```

This is incorrect. It does not clone your list.

Use `.copy()` instead:

```
TempList = MyList.copy()
```