# Python List Copying Garbage Collection

Tags: python-3.x, list, reference, garbage-collection

I have a list `a` and set it to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Then I set `b` to `a`. My goal is to make two seperate versions of `a`, aka, I want `b` to change while `a` dosen't change.
However, when I remove 5 from `b`, `a` becomes, `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, exactly the same as `b`!
My code is shown below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = a
b.remove(5)
print(b, a)
```

Here is my output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: By making a copy of a or better -- by taking a slice of a excluding the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a copy of a, you can use:

```
b = a[:]
```

This question has been [asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference).

Answer (score 1):

or you can take part of the list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a[:4]
print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code without changing the original list

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = a.copy()
```