# Why is my list getting sorted when I am sorting a list that's equivalent? Python

Tags: python

I am trying to set a list = to another list and then sort the new list using .sort(). However, when I print them out to make sure they stored properly, both lists got sorted when I only set the new list to be. Why is this happening? The first print statement is printing the correct unsorted list, the third statement is correctly printing the new sorted list, but the fourth print statement is supposed to be printing the unsorted list but is printing a sorted list.

```
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int)->List[int]:

        print("original list", nums)
        sortedList = nums
        sortedList.sort()
        subset = []
        answer = []
        middle = math.floor((len(nums)/2))
        print("middle is ", middle)
        print("sorted list", sortedList)
        print("unsorted list", nums)
```

Comment: after you do `sortedList = nums` you have two names for the same list, so it doesn't matter which you sort. since there's still only one list, it's sorted. Make a copy instead, or use `sorted()` to make a copy and sort at the same time.

Comment: That was the issue, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `sortedList = nums` means both lists point to the same memory location, this is called assignment by reference, if you want to copy the values only you can do as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference) suggests:

```py
sortedList = nums[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign *sortedList = nums* you are merely copying a reference to *nums*. Thus if you sort *nums*, *sortedList* will refer to that same sorted list. If you don't want that to happen, take a copy - e.g., *sortedList = nums.copy()*

Comment: Oh I never knew that, thank you a lot for the help

Comment: `nums.copy()`? that's a new one on me, and I've been using Python for years!

Comment: @kindall copy() has been available as a list builtin since Python 3. Of course you can still do *sortedList = nums[:]* if you need backward compatibility

Comment: Yeah, it never occurred to me to go looking for a `copy()` method because the existing methods are satisfactory. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [the builtin `sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) which returns a new, sorted list.

```
list1 = [3, 2, 1]
list2 = sorted(list1)
```

Comment: I didn't even realize that I could do that, thank you for your feedback