# Why doesn't list change?

Tags: python, list, reference

In Python:

```
    b = []
    a = np.arange(2)
    b.append(a)
    a = np.arange(4)
    b.append(a)
    print(b) # gives [array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])]
```

Why doesn't it give `[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])]`?

There are a ton of questions going the other way (to make sure the list does not change -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this explanation on referencing and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)).

From the links above I would expect `b[0] == b[1]` because I updated `a`, but this is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks! Is this related to immutable vs mutable values?

Comment: Kinda, yeah. Like you noted below, it has more to do with if you changed the value that is referenced by a variable vs. changing the actual "pointer". Immutable values _can't_ be changed, so any time you do this it does the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a = np.arange(4)` doesn't update the values inside `a`, it reassigns the reference to a new array. This is reflected in `b`, as it has two different arrays as elements.

Comment: Is it correct to say the way to tell is to ask whether I have changed "a" in-place? Since in this case I have not changed it in-place, then it is a new value?

Comment: @PhysicsEnthusiast yes, that would be correct.